# UnAuthorizedError on service bus message send with Node JS

Tags: node.js, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am getting below error on service bus message send and it is hosted on Docker containers in Kubernetes.

Have reviewed the SAS token and it is valid and has "Manage" permissions. using the same token I can send a message in the service bus topic in my local environment but, doesn't work in the container. and throws below error.

```
UnauthorizedError:
       at translate (/consumer/node_modules/ (at translate (/consumer/node_modules/@azure/amqp-common/dist/index.js:908:17)at translate (/consumer/node_modules/@azure/amqp-common/dist/index.js:908:17): azure/amqp-common/dist/index.jsat translate (/consumer/node_modules/@azure/amqp-common/dist/index.js:908:17): 908)
       at Receiver.messageCallback (/consumer/node_modules/ (at Receiver.messageCallback (/consumer/node_modules/@azure/amqp-common/dist/index.js:1230:35)at Receiver.messageCallback (/consumer/node_modules/@azure/amqp-common/dist/index.js:1230:35): azure/amqp-common/dist/index.jsat Receiver.messageCallback (/consumer/node_modules/@azure/amqp-common/dist/index.js:1230:35): 1230)
       at Receiver.emit (at Receiver.emit (events.js:194:15)at Receiver.emit (events.js:194:15): events.jsat Receiver.emit (events.js:194:15): 194)
       at emit (at emit (/consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/util/utils.js:129:24)at emit (/consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/util/utils.js:129:24): /consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/util/utils.jsat emit (/consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/util/utils.js:129:24): 129)
       at Object.emitEvent (at Object.emitEvent (/consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/util/utils.js:140:9)at Object.emitEvent (/consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/util/utils.js:140:9): /consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/util/utils.jsat Object.emitEvent (/consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/util/utils.js:140:9): 140)
       at Receiver._link.on (at Receiver._link.on (/consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/link.js:252:25)at Receiver._link.on (/consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/link.js:252:25): /consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/link.jsat Receiver._link.on (/consumer/node_modules/rhea-promise/dist/lib/link.js:252:25): 252)
       at Receiver.emit (at Receiver.emit (events.js:189:13)at Receiver.emit (events.js:189:13): events.jsat Receiver.emit (events.js:189:13): 189)
       at Receiver.link.dispatch (at Receiver.link.dispatch (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/link.js:59:37)at Receiver.link.dispatch (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/link.js:59:37): /consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/link.jsat Receiver.link.dispatch (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/link.js:59:37): 59)
       at Incoming.on_transfer (at Incoming.on_transfer (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/session.js:361:22)at Incoming.on_transfer (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/session.js:361:22): /consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/session.jsat Incoming.on_transfer (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/session.js:361:22): 361)
       at Session.on_transfer (at Session.on_transfer (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/session.js:749:19)at Session.on_transfer (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/session.js:749:19): /consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/session.jsat Session.on_transfer (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/session.js:749:19): 749)
       at Connection.(anonymous function) [as on_transfer] (at Connection.(anonymous function) [as on_transfer] (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/connection.js:804:30)at Connection.(anonymous function) [as on_transfer] (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/connection.js:804:30): /consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/connection.jsat Connection.(anonymous function) [as on_transfer] (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/connection.js:804:30): 804)
       at c.dispatch (at c.dispatch (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/types.js:910:33)at c.dispatch (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/types.js:910:33): /consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/types.jsat c.dispatch (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/types.js:910:33): 910)
       at Transport.read (at Transport.read (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/transport.js:109:36)at Transport.read (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/transport.js:109:36): /consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/transport.jsat Transport.read (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/transport.js:109:36): 109)
       at SaslClient.read (at SaslClient.read (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/sasl.js:328:26)at SaslClient.read (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/sasl.js:328:26): /consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/sasl.jsat SaslClient.read (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/sasl.js:328:26): 328)
       at Connection.input (at Connection.input (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/connection.js:538:35)at Connection.input (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/connection.js:538:35): /consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/connection.jsat Connection.input (/consumer/node_modules/rhea/lib/connection.js:538:35): 538)
       at TLSSocket.emit (at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13): events.jsat TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13): 189)
```

Can anyone help how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What operation are you trying to perform?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS I am sending a message to topic using service bus.There is a loop where it sends multiple messages to topic.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you would need all 3 permissions (Manage, Send and Listen). Though the documentation states that Manage permission should be enough but I found that not to be true. Can you try with that?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS I tried with creating new SAS token as well. If I use that configuration string in my local environment. it works. but, It doesn't on Docker container in Kubernetes. Totally strange for me. and yes, by using Manage permissions it can do send and receive both.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include all these pertinent details? I am not really the right person to help you out with this but somebody else will. Good luck!

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS Thanks! Yes, I will edit the question and add more details.